# Split screen content in 2 columns : UICollectionViewFlowLayout?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uicollectionview

I have an existing screen with a `UICollectionView`, with some `UICollectionViewCell`s, all bellow one another.
I need to split this screen in 2 columns, and to be able to choose which cell is in column 1 and which in column 2, so i cannot use the Flow layout.

I mean for each cell i need to be able to tell "go in column 1, row 3" ...

Do i need to subclass the `UICollectionViewLayout`, or is there a simpler way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with normal UICollectionViewLayout.

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int column = indexPath.row%2;
    int row = indexPath.row/2;
}
```

Comment: Edited my answer. You can calculate column and row from indexPath.row